# Как изменить CSS который добавляется по ссылке?

Tags: html, css

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'>
```

Нашел готовый CSS, добавил, мне не понравилась ширина столбцов в таблице, как я могу изменить этот параметр? Копировать CSS по ссылке и редактировать его?

Comment: Вы можете просто скопировать данный CSS файл у себя в проекте, отредактировать и подключить с вашего сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переопределяйте свойства c указанием !important, который позволяет повысить приоритет стиля. Допустим в стороннем файле:

```
td.dt-left {
  text-align:left;
}
```

В вашем файле css:

```
td.dt-left {
  text-align:right !important;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло